# MacTeX 2020: "unable to change to format path"

Tags: context, mactex

I installed MacTeX 2020 and can't get ConTeXt to work (does work on another machine where I upgraded from MacTeX 2019). The error is:

```
$ context file.tex
mtx-context     | warning: no format found, forcing remake (commandline driven)
[…] snip lots of lines
resolvers       | formats | changing to format path '/var/folders/rj/hfjmjx796q102y4v23vh038c0000gp/T/luatex-cache/context/a86c089b384a3076dc514ba966a1fac9/formats/luatex'
resolvers       | formats | unable to change to format path '/var/folders/rj/hfjmjx796q102y4v23vh038c0000gp/T/luatex-cache/context/a86c089b384a3076dc514ba966a1fac9/formats/luatex'
mtx-context     | error, no format found with name: cont-en, aborting
system          | total runtime: 5.315 seconds
```

I read [Running Mark IV](https://wiki.contextgarden.net/Running_Mark_IV) from the wiki and tried running

```
context --make
context --make cont-en
```

but they quit with the same `unable to change to format path` message. I assume that is the core problem. After running those commands, I still get the same error when trying to build my PDF.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Have you tried `sudo fmtutil-sys --missing`?

Comment: @AlanMunn I got the solution form the mailing list, see my answer.

Answer (score 3):

I got the solution to this problem from the ConTeXt mailing list ([link to thread](https://mailman.ntg.nl/pipermail/ntg-context/2020/099470.html)), I'll quote from there:

> These messages come from the middle of the file luat-fmt.lua (lines
> 180 and 183, respectively, on my system) when ConTeXt tries to change
> the working directory (that’s what “change” means in this context, just
> moving to another directory, as in cd or chdir).  The relevant extract
> is
>
> ```
> report_format("changing to format path %a",validformatpath)
> lfs.chdir(validformatpath)
> if dir.current() ~= validformatpath then
>   return fatalerror(startupdir,"unable to change to format path %a",validformatpath)
> end
> ```
>
> In your case *validformatpath* is a subdirectory of `$TMPDIR`, under
> `/var/folders/`.  However, if your Mac is anything like mine, `/var` is
> actually a symbolic link to `/private/var`, so that `dir.current()` reports
> a path starting with `/private` and the test fails.
>
> You can work around that by setting `TMPDIR` to some other value, that
> doesn’t start with `/var` -- and not `/tmp` either because that’s also a
> symbolic link :-)  It should work with a temporary directory in your
> home folder.

So what I'm doing is:

```
env TMPDIR=~/tmp context <file>
```

You could set this up as alias in your shell, for example I have this for fish:

```bash
function context
  env TMPDIR=~/tmp /Library/TeX/texbin/context $argv
end
```