# ConTeXt fails to work on Fedora Silvervlue ("Fatal format file error; I'm stymied" followed by "unable to change to format path")

Tags: texlive, context, texmf

On Fedora Silverblue, running in a toolbox, ConTeXt that previously worked well is now refusing to start.

The first error looks like this:

```
(Fatal format file error; I'm stymied)mtx-context | fatal error: return code: 256
```

There is a [FAQ](http://www.texfaq.org/FAQ-formatstymy) item for it but no amount of `fmtutil --all -user`, `sudo fmtutil --all -sys`, `context --make` or `sudo context --make` is working. it still fails.

Understanding the error, the TeX binary does not know which TeX dialect to use. Is that plain TeX, LaTeX, ConTeXt? It's missing the file in the correct format to understand what's going on. Reinstalling texlive in a new toolbox doesn't solve the problem. That's when I see on the error message path relating to my home directory, specifically `~/.cache/texlive`.

I just `rm -rf ~/.cache/texlive` (any good cache can be removed at any time). The error disappears.

Now, `context` return with success error code but no file is generated and there is a suspicious error message on the last line:

```
resolvers       | formats | unable to change to format path '/var/home/mildred/.cache/texlive/luatex-cache/context/c8ffba5311d077c16376bba44d5fa793/formats/luatex'
```

This directory is empty (I removed the cache earlier) and `context --make` does not help either

Answer (score 1):

There is a similar question regarding this particular error here: [MacTeX 2020: "unable to change to format path"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/562747/mactex-2020-unable-to-change-to-format-path)

Relevant explanation of the error [from mailing-list thread](https://mailman.ntg.nl/pipermail/ntg-context/2020/099479.html) is:

> These messages come from the middle of the file luat-fmt.lua (lines 180 and 183, respectively, on my system) when ConTeXt tries to change the working directory (that’s what “change” means in this context, just moving to another directory, as in cd or chdir). The relevant extract is
>
> ```
> report_format("changing to format path %a",validformatpath)
> lfs.chdir(validformatpath)
> if dir.current() ~= validformatpath then
>   return fatalerror(startupdir,"unable to change to format path %a",validformatpath)
> end
> ```
>
> In your case validformatpath is a subdirectory of $TMPDIR, under /var/folders/. However, if your Mac is anything like mine, /var is actually a symbolic link to /private/var, so that dir.current() reports a path starting with /private and the test fails.
>
> You can work around that by setting TMPDIR to some other value, that doesn’t start with /var -- and not /tmp either because that’s also a symbolic link :-) It should work with a temporary directory in your home folder.

Here, the problem does not come from weirs Mac OS X paths but from the fact that the homedit in Fedora Silverblue is a symlink:

```
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 9 Jan  3 18:40 /home -> /var/home
```

This is shown in the error message where the path contains `/home` and not `/var/home`.

When looking at `/usr/bin/context` we can see:

```
#!/usr/bin/sh
export TEXMF=/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist;
export TEXMFCNF=/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c;
export TEXMFCACHE=$HOME/.cache/texlive;
/usr/bin/mtxrun --script context "$@"
```

The solution to your problem is to run (adjusting your username):

```
HOME=/var/home/mildred context yourfile.tex
```